# MoSync Reload - captureImage

Tags: javascript, android, html, mosync

I am developing an app using Mosync Reload 3.3 and I am having issues using the [captureImage](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/captureImage.md.html#capture.captureImage) function to let a phone take a photo and upload it to my server.

Firstly, I only have a Google Nexus 4 for testing and it is not jailbroken. When I call the image capture function:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureImage(function(mediaFiles){ 
        alert(JSON.stringify(mediaFiles)); 
    }, function(error) { 
        alert('An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code); 
    }, {limit: 2}
);
```

My phone lets me take a photo, but in the mediaFiles object that is returned to the success function, the image path doesn't exist on my phone when I try and navigate there. The path says '/data/data/com.mosync.app_ReloadClient/files/saved/RLDPRJmyTestApp/image000.jpg'. When I go to the data folder on my phone it is empty, if I try to create another nested data folder it says file already exists so I guess it could just be a hidden folder I don't have access to?

Anyway, I can't progress further as when I try to upload the file I get an error message from [FileTransfer](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/filetransfer.md.html#FileTransfer) , outputting error code 1 which means the file was not found.

Has anyone had any similar issues who can offer any advice as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have checked storage permission for your app.